# Can I target a parent node with CSS or in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, dom

I'm looking for a solution to append an element (pointer carat) to all `<li>` tags that have an `<ul>` tag member denoting the option for expansion. Other than using JS to scrape through the entire nested menu listing, it would have been nice to do:

```
$('ul:parent').append('<span>&gt;</span>');
```

Any options available?

Comment: Where's your HTML? Show us some HTML please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get a parent in CSS as that only goes down the DOM tree. You can use `parent` in jQuery though:

```
$('ul').parent().append('<span>&gt;</span>');
```

If you're trying to find all `li` elements which contain a `ul`, you can use `has`:

```
$('li').has('ul').append('<span>&gt;</span>');
```

Comment: I know.  Bummer.  I was hoping that someone had a workaround. I want to get ALL parents of <ul> tags in one fell swoop.  If not I'll just kick my can down JS road.

Comment: then use parents instead parent

Comment: Whoa.  Really?  Trying it now.

Comment: Haha.  I was just about to tell you Rory to make it an official answer so that I could mark it correct.  I used:

var $parents = this.$el.find('ul').parent();

Comment: Sorry C-link, $.parents() traverses all ancestors of a single element.  I need the immediate parents of a set of elements.

Comment: Hmm.  Now seeing your edit.  Have you any idea which is more performant?

Answer (score 0):

CSS4 will have a parent selector, but that is not supported by any browsers today:

```
$ul > li {
  ...
}
```